# Number of images per class in dataset, PyTorch

Tags: pytorch

I am working on an image dataset where images are classified in 10 classes (CIFAR10 dataset). I am using PyTorch. Please, I would like to know how to determine the number of images per class by looping through the dataset. Thanks in advance for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it two-fold.

- First create a dictionary img_dict which has all the classes of CIFAR10 dataset. Initialize all values to 0.
- Next loop through the dataset and keep on incrementing the values against the class key in the img_dict

```py
dataset = CIFAR10(root='data/', download=True, transform=ToTensor())
dataset_size = len(dataset)
classes = dataset.classes
num_classes = len(dataset.classes)
img_dict = {}
for i in range(num_classes):
    img_dict[classes[i]] = 0

for i in range(dataset_size):
    img, label = dataset[i]
    img_dict[classes[label]] += 1

img_dict
```

You will get output as below:

[number of images per class:

[image: 1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgWRw.png)

Comment: This will take a long time to loop through the datasets

Answer (score 0):

Here's a faster way to do it:

```py
from collections import Counter

dataset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root=os.getcwd(), download=True, transform=ToTensor())
idx_to_class = {v:k for k, v in dataset.class_to_idx.items()}  # Index to class mapping

idx_distribution = dict(Counter(dataset.targets))
class_distribution = {idx_to_class[k]:v for k, v in idx_distribution.items()}

print(class_distribution)
```

Result:

```py
Result:
{
  'frog': 5000, 
  'truck': 5000, 
  'deer': 5000,
  'automobile': 5000, 
  'bird': 5000, 
  'horse': 5000, 
  'ship': 5000, 
  'cat': 5000, 
  'dog': 5000, 
  'airplane': 5000
}
```

Colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11hHy0YNwgEhE5nmQqXRliE4KkIzqjBeN?usp=sharing